# Pagination of data in grails

Tags: grails, pagination

I get my data from my back-end team in a ***JSON*** format. Now i want those data to be **paginated** on selection of criteria like if i select 20 from drop-down i want those 1000 of data to be paginated displaying 20 data on each page. Back-end request is not done here. I am using *grails* as my language.

Thank you ! in advance.

Comment: This question looks remarkably similar to another question asked minutes later by another user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559944/grails-load-data-according-to-page-size.

Comment: Another one similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436579/change-count-of-displaing-items-in-paginate-section?answertab=active#tab-top