# Grails: load data according to page size

Tags: grails

I have a view which displays data ->parsed json which comes after sendig request to back end.

The request parameters contains page ad page size which defualts to page=1 and page size to 20.

Now i require a pagination in view that helps to see the records by allowing users to select 10 records per page,20 records and 100.
The data parsed json is already available in view .
PLz, help me what should i do cause when user for the first time opens the page only 20 record should be displayed and when he select 100 record the page it should show 100 records.

Comment: What are you using for pagination? Paginate tag or some javascript library?

Comment: i have used javascript library to paginate.

Comment: Can you mention which library? pls add some code here..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking that you have an `HTML drop down` that says 20 results (and 50 and 100 and so on) and then when he changes this, it should show on the page right?
For this you can set an event handler for the dropdown's `onChange()` event which makes an AJAX call to your server (and passes the number of results required along with the offset if any as parameters) - and returns your results which you can display.
This is how I'd do it.

Comment: Yes ,,when i change the drop down and click it calls a function    now what should i do to get 100 records  from parsed json data in the controller to display in the page ,,function Getdata(parameters) $.blockUI();
   jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:params,
    url:'<g:createLink action="abcd"/>',
    success:function(data,textStatus){
     jQuery('#r').html(data);
     $.unblockUI();
    },

Comment: in your grails controller you can send lists and maps by simply doing `render stuff as JSON`. you will get this as the `data` variable in your jquery `success(data, textStatus){}` function. Once you have the `data` you can do stuff like:
`for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){$("#myTable").append(data[i].name)}`
etc... Is this what you're trying to ask?

Comment: Yes i was searching for something like this thank you i will try and see if it works or not .