# Change count of displaing items in paginate section

Tags: grails, pagination

Is there any way to change count of displaying beans into paginate section by user in grails 2x? I can not find this in grails docs. It means something like (see itemsPerPage)

```
<g:paginate total="${beanInstanceTotal}" itemsPerPage="[10,20,50]" .../>
```

I think that this is obvious functionality for pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `max` parameter in g:paginate.

From the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html):
*max (optional) - The number of records to display per page (defaults to 10). Used ONLY if params.max is empty*

You can then parse `params.max` in the controller and pass it to the query.

**EDIT:**
I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. The combo box you described is not available in the default `<g:paginate>` tag. I had this same issue in my application and implemented the select item with the awesome [Remote Pagination plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/remote-pagination). Usage is described in [the docs](https://github.com/amitjain1982/remote-pagination).

```
<util:remotePaginate controller="book" action="filter" total="${Book.count()}" update="listTemplateDivId"
              max="20" pageSizes="[10:'10 Per Page', 20: '20 Per Page', 50:'50 Per Page',100:'100 Per Page']"/>
```